# Python PyQt5: AttributeError: 'QTabWidget' object has no attribute 'setTabVisible'

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

This is an error the debugger in PyCharm does not catch but when running the script from the command line or from 'idle', the interpreter catches it.

I put a dummy line in using the setToolTip attribute just ahead of the line that was failing and it worked ok.

I'm a little bumfuzzled. Please help.

```
    # failure occurs here with
    # Traceback (most recent call last):
    # File "D:\PythonApps\Books_db_utility\walk_dir_tree.py", line 1584, in <module>
    #       main_window = MainWindow(ini_file=None, _path=path)
    # File "D:\PythonApps\Books_db_utility\walk_dir_tree.py", line 126, in __init__
    #       self.initUi()
    # File "D:\PythonApps\Books_db_utility\walk_dir_tree.py", line 209, in initUi
    #       self.main_tab_widget.setTabVisible(2, True)
    # AttributeError: 'QTabWidget' object has no attribute 'setTabVisible' 
    self.main_tab_widget.setTabVisible(2, True)
    self.main_tab_widget.setTabVisible(3, False)
```

Another question: I would like to include a zip file with this question with the .py files with the code and the on generated with pyuic5. Can I do that?

Thanks,
sherril

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't attach files to your questions... just write some code.

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using? That member function has not always been available.

Comment: Tab visibility has been introduced in Qt5.15. Check with `from PyQt5 import QtCore; print(QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)`. Besides, you said "I put a dummy line in using the setToolTip attribute just ahead of the line that was failing and it worked ok.": do you mean that if you use `setToolTip` *before* `setTabVisible()`, the error doesn't happen? If that's so, please provide a [mre] (please read that link **very carefully**: you must post code that has to be *both* minimal **and** reproducible, meaning that we should be able to copy, paste and run it, and it shouldn't be more than 100-150 lines).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's magic. I was using the PyCharm 2021.2.3 (Community Edition), Python 3.10 interpreter and PyQt5 5.15.6 when I got the exception I mentioned in my original post.

I changed the interpreter to Python 3.8 with PyQt5 5.15.4 and ***voila*** it worked like I expected it should.

So, I changed the interpreter back to the Python 3.10 that I was originally using and ***voila*** it worked like I expected it should.

Thence, I ran it from the command line (Python 3.8 PyQt5 5.15.2 from an Anaconda3 distribution; this was the interpreter that I "did not" refer to in my original question and ***bummer*** it failed again.

So, I replace pyqt5 5.15.2 with 5.15.6 (using pip) in the Anaconda3 distribution's file and ***voila*** it worked like I expected it should. (pip may have been a no-no; I suppose I will learn in time.)

I do not intend to reinstall the Pyqt5 5.15.2 in the Anaconda3 unless someone is really interested in was it the version or was something corrupted.

Answer (score -2):

Probably you didn't import correctly the package so it couldn't be found.

Did you import it in the beggining of the code:

`from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QAction, QTabWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel`

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pyqt5-qtabwidget/

Here is the documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html

Comment: This is *clearly* not the problem, as the AttributeError does not refer to `QTabWidget` (which doesn't necessarily need to be imported, the object already exists), but to the `setTabVisible` attribute of `QTabWidget`.